# XML attribute tag

Tags: xml, odoo

please can help me to understand this part of code (XML with Odoo) exactly the `<attribute>` tag

```
<xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='account_id']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute> 
</xpath>

<xpath expr="//field[@name='number']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="string">PO Number</attribute>
    <attribute name="readonly">0</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Not a python question.

Answer (score 0):

The first XPath expression is making the field `account_id` of an embedded tree view invisible. Actually it is adding the attribute `invisible="1"` to the field which would look something like:

```xml
<tree>
    <field name="name" />
    <!-- some other fields -->
    <field name="account_id" invisible="1" />
</tree>
```

The second XPath is adding/change the attributes `string` and `readonly` for the first field definition with attribute `name` equal to "number" in the inherited view. `string` is the field label in that view, which is obviously changed to something other than the usual label and it seems normally the field is readonly, which is changed to readable by `readonly="0"`.

Answer (score 0):

This means :

1. `invisble = 1` ===> calculate the field and hide it.
2. `name` ===>  Label of current field.
3. `readonly = 0` ===> We can edit the value of this field.

If `readonly = 1` maens we can see the field but we can't edit the field